# main domain + subdomain + CSS not found

Tags: google-app-engine

I have one `dispatch.yaml` that splits 2 services; `admin_main.py` that controls the admin login, and `main.py` that controls the user landing. My problem is that `admin_main.py` does not see its own CSS that I directed it to it. However, it keeps matching with the `main.py` CSS. 
my files are structured as

```
admin

 |assets

    |CSS

      +styles.min.css

www

  |assets

     |CSS

       +styles.min.css
```

`dispatch.yaml`:

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "example.net/"
    service: default
  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "app-example.appspot.com/"
    service: default

  # Default service serves simple hostname request.
  - url: "admin.example.net/"
    service: admin
  - url: "admin-dot-app-example.appspot.com/"
    service: admin
```

`admin_main.py`:

```
service: admin
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /assets/css/styles.min.css
  static_files: admin/assets/css/styles.min.css
  upload: admin/assets/css/styles.min.css

  - url: /.*
  script: subdomain.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

`main.py`:

```
service: default
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

default_expiration: "4d 5h"

handlers:

- url: /assets/css
  static_dir: www/assets/css

- url: /assets/img
  static_dir: www/assets/img


- url: /.*
  script: main.app


libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: latest
- name: jinja2
  version: latest
```

in the `.html` the links to the CSS are

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.min.css">`

for both landing sites. But that shouldn't be a problem since the `dispatch.yaml` separate the incoming calls, right?
I'm not really sure what is causing the problem. Also, I'm new to yaml and I been reading it's documentation.

Comment: Note that the standard name for the dispatcher file is `dispatch.yaml`, not `dispatcher.yaml`, I'm not sure if using a different name works OK or not. Try renaming it to the standard name. Also check in the request logs which service actually receives the request to determine what routing decision was made.

Comment: @DanCornilescu ... it is `dispatch.yaml` it was just a typo

Comment: Do you see the problem on the local development server or on GAE?

Comment: the GAE ... I didn't know how to use the local development server for a subdomain so I had to upload and run

Comment: Can you check the corresponding request logs in the developer console, expand the log entry and show the request path and hostname (right before the ms/cpu_ms/cpu_usd info) as well as the which service actually received it (which you can determine by filtering the logs using the top left dropdown menu button)?

Comment: I did check... it goes to the right place, it passes by the dispatch to admin_main.py to subdomain.app ... still it doesn't see the right CSS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166501/discussion-between-dan-cornilescu-and-mohammedalsafwan).

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is to store every `CSS` in the same file, and give them different names. Then in `app.yaml` in the `handlers` section add this:

```
- url: "/assets/css/(.*\\.(css))$"
  static_files: {CSS_DIR_IN_PROJECT}/\1
  upload: {CSS_DIR_IN_PROJECT}/.*\.(css)$
  application_readable: true
```

that was my only way of solving the problem